# MYSQL - Can't group a summed column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with faktura_kroner (decimal 9,2), and faktura_dato (BIGINT 11, which is a unix timestamp).

I am trying to get the sum of faktura_kroner per month so I can use it in a chart, but am struggling a bit to find the correct sql query. Also it is unique by year. So October 2016 should not be grouped with October 2017 as an example.

Any help appreciated..

```
SELECT sum(faktura_kroner) as sum_faktura, 
MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) as month, 
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) as year
    FROM 
    faktura
    WHERE 
    user_id = 1
    AND
    virksomhet_id = 1
    GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) DESC, 
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) ASC, faktura_dato DESC;
```

Comment: Right now I am getting two matches for december 2017, instead of one as a result

Comment: What&#39;s the expected output and what are you getting from the query? You can try to group by the exact same thing you are selecting for month. Also, group by doesn't have desc or asc. That's for order by.

Comment: Yeh, I wanted to group by month and year. Ankit's answer below did what I wanted, after a small adjustment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT sum(faktura_kroner) as sum_faktura
      ,MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) as month
      ,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) as year
FROM faktura
WHERE user_id = 1
AND
virksomhet_id = 1
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) as month
        ,YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(faktura_dato)) as year
```